# Could not find a Provider - Flutter

Tags: flutter, stream, provider

I want to provide a stream to my DecksList widget, so I initialized a provider in MyApp. It throws a ProviderNotFoundError. What can be a reason for that behavior ?

```
I/flutter (27768): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (27768): The following ProviderNotFoundError was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
I/flutter (27768): Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Stream<List<Deck>>> above this DecksList Widget
```

Open the image to look at the MyApp widget:
[app widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XyjF.png)

DecksList inside Home widget :

```
class DecksList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DecksListState createState() => _DecksListState();
}

class _DecksListState extends State<DecksList> {
  Stream<List<Deck>> decks;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    decks = Provider.of<Stream<List<Deck>>>(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Deck>>(
        stream: decks,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final decksList = snapshot.data ?? List();
          return ListView.builder(
//          to scroll lists together
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: decksList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final Deck itemDeck = decksList[index];
              return DeckTile(
                deckItem: itemDeck,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return FlashcardsDeck(
                      deckId: itemDeck.id,
                    );
                  }));
                },
                onLongPress: () {},
              );
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you initialized by calling `ChangeNotifierWidget` or  `MultiChilChangeNotifier` ?

Comment: Typically this error happens when you're not using a descendent context. But it's strange, you're calling `Home()` (and therefore `DecksList()`) from inside a builder, and it should work. You could try wrapping the `StreamBuilder` in a `Consumer<Stream<List<Deck>>>`.  What's the purpose of having a stateful widget, caching the stream value?

Comment: @user8773560 No, I didn't

Comment: @frank06 The purpose of having a stateful widget with initializing a stream in initState is due to every time DecksList widget rebuilds it restarts the stream. And the purpose to provide a stream using provider is to fix the issue with stream restarting

Comment: Sure, that is correct. Does `Provider.of<List<Deck>>(context);` return anything at all?

Comment: @SergiyVergun how are you registering the stream with provider? I wrote this: https://flutterigniter.com/future-async-called-multiple-times/ , maybe you find something useful under "Cleaner ways"

Comment: @frank06, yes it returns the list. I removed a StreamBuilder and now just build a list with data taken from StreamProvider<List<Deck>>, it works but doesn't refresh the list, when data has been changed

Comment: @frank06 I've read an article, its great. So I've tried to memoize the stream using hooks, but stream still has been restarting when I changed the tab in bottom bar (so the Scaffold's body changed), maybe the problem could be in the way I implemented what widget should've been showed with bottom bar's tab changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with moor library.
Here is an issue https://github.com/simolus3/moor/issues/329

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.